# How change gray background by item on another, when he is selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[[image]]1]

```
 <FormControl>
        <Select
          value={val}
          onChange={handleSelect}
          input={<BootstrapInput />}
          displayEmpty
          // classes={{selectMenu: { marginTop: 50 }}}
          MenuProps={{...menuProps, classes: {paper: classes.paper, selected: classes.root, option: classes.root}}}
          classes={{
              icon: classes.icon,
              // selectMenu: classes.selectMenu,
              // select: classes.root
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={0} disabled classes={{
              root: classes.disabledMenuItem
          }}>
            Test
          </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="" style={{display: 'none'}}>Select</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Me need is to change the background on green instead gray. When the user clicks and opens the dropdown again, he expects a green background, not gray. Gray is default.

Comment: check this doc for the menu component https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menus then you can override what you want to change with https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop if the theming from MUI not suit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point to the root and change the selected color and hover color like this:

```
      root: {
    '&$selected': {
      backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
      color: 'white',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
      },
    },
  },
```